# PHP snippet to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, converters

I have the following PHP code:

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $file) {

   $is_main = ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] == $_POST['images'][0]) ? 'main' : $i;

}
```

What would be the translation to Laravel?

I've tried:

```
$files = Input::file('images');
foreach($files as $file) {

   $is_main = ($file->getClientOriginalName() == $file[0]) ? 'main': $i;

}
```

But it doesn't work, what would be the correct translation?

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Marty I mean that it's not translated correctly by me, I'm not getting the expected result since there's something with the syntax. What would be the correct translation? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes but what's happening instead of the expected result? Do you get an error? Does the code almost do what you want? Does it just do nothing?

Comment: @Marty Does nothing, the $is_main variable is expected to return 'main' and insert it to a database. But since the syntax is wrong according to me nothing is sent to the database. I don't receive any errors, it just doesn't work

Comment: Where does `$i` come from?

Comment: @dan-klasson It's an incrementing variable but you can dismiss that, I'm just interested in converting this part **$_FILES['images']['name'][$i] == $_POST['images'][0]** -- Thanks in advance

Comment: Well maybe that's because your if statements return false.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files) you should be doing something like:

```
if (Input::file('photo')->isValid())
{
    $name = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $name);
}
```

Comment: btw the `getClientOriginalName` get both the name and the extension.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer but it's not what I asked, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'd like to convert this PHP snippet  **$is_main = ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] == $_POST['images'][0]) ? 'main' : $i;** To Laravel -- thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some try and error I could finally solve it, this is the code:

```
$is_main = ($file->getClientOriginalName() == Input::all()["images"][0]) ? true : NULL;
```

Thanks to those who helped